# firebase.messaging is not a function when running mocha tests through babel-register

Tags: webpack, tdd, mocha.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, babeljs

Running :

```
 "test": "set NODE_PATH=./app&& mocha --require ./test/testSetup.js --compilers babel-core/register \"./app/**/*.test.js\""
```

Outputs this error:

> var messaging = exports.messaging = firebase.messaging();
>
> TypeError: firebase.messaging is not a function

referring to this:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

export const database = firebase.database()
export const firebaseAuth = firebase.auth()
export const messaging = firebase.messaging()

messaging.onMessage(payload => {
  handleInAppMessages(payload)
})
```